# is there a way to condense a vector (C++)?

Tags: c++, vector, loops

I have a sparsely populated vector that I populated via hashing, so elements are scattered randomly in the vector. Now what I want to do is iterate over every element in that vector. What I had in mind was essentially condensing the vector to fit the number of elements present, removing any empty spaces. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: What is it a vector of? And how can you tell if an element is unused?

Comment: The first idea, obviously, would be to see whether std::tr1::unordered_map could be used (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html).  It contains iterators.

Comment: Why not use an `unordered_map`?

Comment: it is a vector of vectors of strings. so i guess an empty address in the vector will be Vector[x].empty().

Comment: the thing is it is for an assignment and i can't use maps or sets

Comment: Seems the obvious solution is to write an iterator that ignores the empty elements.

Comment: Indeed, creating a `view` seems necessary, however beware that the iterator will need to check it does not overrun the end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you save the additionally needed information during insertion of the elements (e.g. links to the previous / next element compared to a linked list) or you make one pass over all the elements and remove the unnecessary ones.

The first solution costs you some space (approx. 8 bytes / entry), the second costs you one pass over all elements. Depending on the scenario, one or both possibilities might not be useful.

Comment: next to the space-cost, you also have the bookkeeping cost during insert/erase (including finding the previous/next entries).

Answer (score 1):

You can condense using a version of run-length encoding.
You go over the original vector and create a new "condensed" vector which contains alternating values - a value from the original and a count of the empty spaces to the next value. For example this:

```
3 - - - - 4 - - 7 3 - - - 9 -
```

turns to this:

```
3 4 4 2 7 0 3 3 9 1
```